# How to get authorization id when payment is done using paypal express checkout

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to get the authorization id from sales order if the payment is done using the paypal express checkout.
I am able to get payer id and correlation id.

Can I get authorization id using these two values if yes How?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call our `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) to finalize the transaction once the buyer has returned back to your (specifically, to the page indicated in your RETURNURL parameter).
After you've called `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, the response will contain a `PAYMENTSTATUS=Pending` and a `TRANSACTIONID`. Its value will be your authorizationID.

You can subsequently capture this authorization with our `DoCapture` [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/).

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413071/validate-paypal-transaction-id-passed-by-android-in-magento-site)